# i cant publish library and update it

Tags: npm, publish, npm-publish

i want to update existing library. i used npm publish and also logged in to npm before.
i got this error:
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to http://192.168.1.100:4001
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`

i used `npm adduser` and i logged in, even used npm whoami and get my username back but when i use npm publish again i`ll get this error again.
my npm register is http://registry.npmjs.org (even tried by http://localhost:4001/ config) and added publish config to pakage.json:
"publishConfig": {
"registry": "http://192.168.1.100:4001"
}

i also logged in many time.
please help me fix this issue

i searched in many form but didnt find anything